# Can I have a File-instance with content without saving the file?

Tags: ruby, file, paperclip, render, temporary-files

For paperclip I have a file that I add programmatically. The file is a generated PDF. So basically I don't need this file to be saved to my server's HDD. What I do now is the following:

```
@tempfile = Tempfile.open( ['','.pdf'], nil, 'wb', encoding: "ASCII-8BIT") do |file|
  file << render_to_string( pdf: "pdf_file.pdf", layout: "pdf", template: "projects/generatePDF" )
end

@export.pdf = File.open( @tempfile.path )     # Paperclip Attachment
```

These are three steps: Create, write, open. So I'm wondering if we can do this easier, something like the following would be great:

```
@export.pdf = File.new( render_to_string( pdf: "pdf_file.pdf", layout: "pdf", template: "projects/generatePDF" ) )
```

Comment: Yes, it does! Seems faster too, but didn't test it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a stringio - this is a subclass of IO that is backed by a string rather than a file.